# Why are/aren't these functions members of the exponential family?

Tags: exponential-family

I am currently trying to learn about the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) of distributions. I am trying to understand [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/355302/163242) question and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/355323/163242) answer from Xi'an. I have the same function:

$$f(x; \sigma, \tau)=
\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{\sigma} e^{-(x - \tau)}/\sigma &\text{if}\, x\geq \tau\\
      0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

However, it still isn't clear to me why this is **not** a member of the exponential family. On the other hand, it is said that the function

$$f_{\varphi}(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \varphi x^{\varphi - 1} &\text{if}\, 0 < x < 1, \varphi > 0\\
      0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

actually **is** a member of the (one-parameter) exponential family.

Why is the first function **not** a member of the exponential family? Furthermore, what is the reasoning behind why one is a member of the family and yet the other is not?

---

The 'duplicate' does not provide the clarification of the reasoning here [Is the negative exponential distribution a member of the exponential family?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355302/is-the-negative-exponential-distribution-a-member-of-the-exponential-family) and here [Is the negative exponential distribution a member of the exponential family?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355302/is-the-negative-exponential-distribution-a-member-of-the-exponential-family/355323#355323). I was really looking for a 'simpler' explanation of things so that I could understand.

Comment: Is $\tau$ fixed?

Comment: In the duplicate I provide a general procedure to test whether a family is Exponential or not and I explain the reasoning behind it.  It is easy to apply in your case.

Comment: @whuber But this does not provide the clarification of the reasoning here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355302/is-the-negative-exponential-distribution-a-member-of-the-exponential-family and here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355302/is-the-negative-exponential-distribution-a-member-of-the-exponential-family/355323#355323 . I was really looking for a 'simpler' explanation of things so that I could understand.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy That's a good question. The example doesn't mention anything about being "fixed", but one would presume that, since the $x$ in $f(x; \sigma, \tau)$ are variable, then the $\sigma$ and $\tau$ must be fixed, no?